# How I disable/remove the touchstart event from videojs?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I want to disable touchstart event in videojs using preventDefault.

```
player.on('touchstart', (e) => { e.preventDefault() });
```

but I get this error:

```
Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.
```

I don't have the handler to use `removeEventListener` either.

What I can do to remove this event?

Comment: this is not works for me

Comment: I want to disable this event and add my own. so touch-events are not good.

Comment: yes, player.off('touchstart') doesn't works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove event try this :

```
 player.off('touchstart',function(){})
```

If you want to customize and want to prevent default try below :

```
player.on('touchstart', (e) => { e.preventDefault() },{passive: false});
```

Events can also be removed altogether by refraining from providing a function:

```
player.off('touchstart');
```

Or an array can be provided:

```
const eventsToRemove = [
  'mousemove',
  'mouseover',
  'mouseup',
  'mousedown',
  'mouseleave',
  'touchstart'
];

player.off(eventsToRemove);
```

For more details :
https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Methodsoff

Comment: did you check this code yourself? because it doesn't work

Comment: still looking on it  , will come back to you

Comment: can you try the first option?

Comment: I'm afraid this did not work, the event above or others such as `mousemove` won't be prevented with the method above.

Comment: @csalmeida feel free to update the answer if it was not working why did Jon accept this

Comment: Not trying to create a conflict, I'm not sure why he accepted as he mentioned it did not in his previous comment. ` player.off('touchstart');` worked for me everywhere but Chrome. In Chrome I've had to listen to the `canplay` event and remove the desired event once `canplay` was fired. I'm unsure whether there is a better way of doing this.